# nodejs mysql pagination via prepared Query statement returns error forEach property undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

The nodejs code below works fine when used to retrieve content from database. now when i tried to get content via pagination as per code below via prepared query statement

```
   db.query('SELECT * FROM posts1 limit row=?, rowperpage=?', [parseInt(row),parseInt(rowperpage)], function (error, results, fields) {

});
```

it returns error "**cannot read property forEach of undefined**"

below is the full code

```
exports.display = function (req, res) {
var row = 0;
var rowperpage = 3;

console.log(row);
console.log(rowperpage);


var objs1 = []; 
    db.query('SELECT * FROM posts1 limit row=?, rowperpage=?', [parseInt(row),parseInt(rowperpage)], function (error, results, fields) {

   // db.query('SELECT * FROM posts1', function (error, results, fields) {

  results.forEach(function(row) {

             var id = row.id;
            var title = row.title;
            var content = row.content;
var shortcontent = row.content;
var link = row.link;


objs1.push({
id: id, 
title: title,
shortcontent: shortcontent,
content: content,
link: link,

});

});
res.end(JSON.stringify(objs1));

});



}
```

Comment: Alter query statement and change the input to an array of arrays: `'SELECT * FROM posts1 limit (row, rowperpage) values = ?', [[parseInt(row),parseInt(rowperpage)]]`

Comment: Thanks for the insight but unfortunately, it does  not solve the issue. still shows the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code below, solve the issue

```
//parse int Convert String to number 
      let startNum = parseInt(row);
      let LimitNum = parseInt(rowperpage);


var objs1 = []; 
 db.query("SELECT * FROM ?? limit ? offset ?", ["posts1",LimitNum,startNum], function (error, results, fields) {
```

Thanks